# Converting Log-Returns Back to Prices in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, garch

I am a beginner of the R software v.3.2.5.

I fitted a hybrid ARMA+GARCH stochastic model to a sample of log-returns on an exchange rate using the rugarch package functions. The fitted(modelfitNUMBER) option returns the fitted values in terms of log-returns. So my question is:

How can I convert those fitted log-returns back to exchange rates using R and/or Excel?

Is it correct to run the following: exp(fittedlogreturn-t)*actualexchangerate-t-1?

I already browsed through many posts on this topic but found nothing enlightening.

Comment: I do not know if taking exp(fittedlogreturnt)*actualpricet-1 is correct

Comment: So what function call did you use to convert the returns into logs in the first place?

Comment: In the first place, I used this function diff(log(exchangerates)) to get the log-returns. Those logreturns are then fitted with the modelfit function of the rugarch package.

Comment: Log gives natural logs, so yes, exp is the correct inverse function

Comment: yes thanks. But my real doubt was on the kind of price that I need to multiply to the exponential of log-returns. Should this price be the one from the actual(observed series)?

Comment: This question isn't so much a technical problem with R as a problem on mathematical transformations of data and would probably be better on Cross Validated.

Comment: Ok yes it probably is more of a mathematical. Thank you all for the help.